# nodejs put data in an input

Tags: html, node.js, input, getelementbyid

I have a form with an input:

```
<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input class="form-control" name="email" id="email"  value="">
```

In my function NodeJS:(I search in my database with an id and I recover his email)

```
 models.User2.findOne({_id: idusersession})   
            .then(function (content) {

           var mail = content.email;
});
```

I want to put this variable mail in my HTML page. So, when the HTML page is called, data is automatically added in my input.

I tried:

```
document.getElementByID("email").value = mail;
```

But no success. Apparently, `document.getElementByID()` doesn't exist in NodeJS.

Comment: Do you try to render HTML from server? If yes, I recommend you paying attention to template engines like swig, mustaches, jade etc. You need to specify file path (path to your HTML) and use special syntax in your HTML (according to chosen template engine). Please check the links below:

[jade](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-template-engines.html)

[swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/)

[mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `Node.js` [template engines](https://paularmstrong.github.io/node-templates/) to achieve this functionality.  Upon each request `Node.js` will generate HTML from your templates on the server and serve it to the browser with either all the values from MongoDB directly in HTML tags or in embedded JavaScript code so that the can be set by JavaScript in the browser (what you tried to do in your example).

Here is an example of using EJS templating https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

An alternative approach is to serve data with a `Node.js` RESTful API and access it from your HTML with [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: Thank you very much for you help. Your solution with "EJS templating" is interesting.